# How do I slowly migrate topics out of a Kafka node?

Tags: apache-kafka

Imagine I have a kafka node that holds a lot of topics, the disk is degraded so I have to start moving topics out of it to the other nodes in the cluster. Kafka manager allows me to do that but the process is cumersome and requires a lot of clicks.

The simplest solution to prevent most clicking would be to just click on all topics but this is obviously not ideal as there will be a lot of disruption from all consumers all at once (and a lot of disk and network stuff changing all at the same time).

Is there a tool or something I could use (or an API I could call) that would allow me to slowly move topics one by one instead?

Kind of like running the reassign and getting the plans but programatically, I'd rather not do bash magic for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a couple tools that can do it:

- https://github.com/Yelp/kafka-utils
- https://github.com/linkedin/cruise-control
- https://github.com/DataDog/kafka-kit